# Deploying to Heroku fails

Tags: node.js, heroku, node-modules, heroku-cli

I am having trouble deploying my app on Heroku when this command is running `git push heroku master` it fails due to a syntax error in the node_modules.

`remote:        node_modules/mixin-deep/index.js -> dist/node_modules/mixin-deep/index.js`

`remote:        node_modules/mixin-deep/node_modules/is- 
   extendable/index.js -> dist/node_modules/mixin- deep/node_modules/is-extendable/index.js`

`remote: SyntaxError: node_modules/mkdirp/bin/cmd.js: 'return' outside of function (13:4)`

`remote:   11 | if (argv.help) {`

`remote:   12 |     fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/usage.txt').pipe(process.stdout);`

`remote: > 13 |     return;`

`remote:      |     ^`

`remote:   14 | }`



`remote:   16 | var paths = argv._.slice();`

`remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE`

`remote: npm ERR! errno 1`

`` remote: npm ERR! backend@1.0.0 build: `node node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js ./ --source-maps --out-dir dist` ``

`remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1`

`remote: npm ERR!`

`remote: npm ERR! Failed at the backend@1.0.0 build script.`

`remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely` 
`additional logging output above.`

`remote:`

Someone had the same issue on GitHub that was solved, but I still don't understand it, if anyone knows a better fix to the error or can help elaborate the solution on GitHub it would be super.
 here's the link https://github.com/fsevents/fsevents/issues/184

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: I haven't able to find the mkdirp folder in the node_modules folder, but that error occurs when the program is installing the dependencies.

Comment: Are you trying to create a directory on heroku server? Because you can't, might be that's the error.

Comment: I don't think so. I am just following the steps on Heroku for deploying an app, and git push heroku master is one of the steps but its the one causing errors.

Comment: I added more information from the error I am getting hopefully that can clarify things

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/fsevents/fsevents/issues/184#issuecomment-360997296), and if you can share the code I can resolve this issue for sure

Comment: Are you using babel?

Comment: @neilveil that's the solution I didn't understand, if you could explain it for it would be super. also, my code has some 10 something files do you want me to post all of it?

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan yes, I am using babel

Comment: @ai006 Make sure the node_modules is excluded from Babel transpilation, heroku will automatically install the required modules from npm

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan how can I do that ?